# Calculating a complex integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{4\cos z}{z}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Take

\begin{equation}
f(z)= \frac{4\cos z}{z}, 
\end{equation}

then I want to find the integral of it over $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the circle $|z|=7$.

Using Cauchy formula, I get

\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{4\cos z}{z}dz=f(0)2\pi i=8\pi i.
\end{equation}

But how do I calculate this with respect to the  boundary of $\gamma$? I have just calculated it without any respect to it, so far.

Then, I want to check what the contour would be, if the integral was equal to 11 and the function was simply generalized to f(z).   How can that be done?

Comment: the boundary just tell you how many residues of the integrand you must consider. The integrand have just one residue at zero, and the given contour surrounds zero.

Comment: What does it mean to implement the boundary of $\gamma$?

Comment: Based on what I have learned, the only way to use the boundary is to see whether $a$ is inside it or not.

Comment: Do you mean how you can compute it by directly using a parametrization of $\gamma$? This is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Does $\gamma$ need to be a closed contour? If it is just a line segment the answer is quite straightforward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the Residue theorem. It says that in a simply connected region bounded by a contour($\gamma$) such as this where the function $f$ is analytic in the region except for a finite number of points $\{a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}\}$.

$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz=2i\pi\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{Res}_{z=a_{i}}f(z)$$.

Using this you get your answer correctly $2i\pi\text{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=2i\pi\cdot 4 = 8i\pi$.

Essentially if you want to make more sense out of it.

Then you consider the Laurent series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{4\cos(z)}{z}$. about $z=0$.

You get $\displaystyle 4\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^{3}}{4!}-...\right)$.

And you use the fact that when you integrate on the contour $\gamma(|z|=7)$. You get the integrals of the form $\int_{\gamma}z^{n}\,dz=0$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1\}$. and the integral is $2i\pi$ when $n=-1$. Using this you can sort of make sense of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Sauron. See my comment on $a$ inside or not the circle $|z|=7$. Is that an oversimplification?

Comment: You mean you are confused about interior points and boundary points?. In that case you can refer to wikipedia or any basic analysis book where point set topology is mentioned. ? . If you mean how is the integral on the boundary related to the residues in the region interior to the boundary. Then as I said , Cauchy's Residue Theorem gives you the required relation.

Comment: @vqngs . Okay I see your updated post. Use the method I did using the Laurent Series expansion.

Comment: Yes, it is the latter. The reason I ask, is because if I am ought to do the inverse, that is find a region $\gamma$ such that the integral is = 11, then I am not sure how to proceed with the residue theorem.

Comment: Well that is not possible. The function is analytic everywhere in the complex plane except for at $z=0$. So if you take ANY contour $\gamma$ (Not necessarily circular) , Then if if $z=0$ lies in the interior of the region then the integral is $8i\pi$ and if the point $z=0$ is outside the region then the integral is just $0$ by Cauchy-Goursat Theorem. So the value of $11$ is not possible.

Comment: and @vqngs you should include the question in the original post. That is one reason why you are discouraged from asking isolated questions. You directly ask that how can I find a $\gamma$ such that the integral on it is $11$ and then share your thoughts on it.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron What if the contour passes through $z=0$?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron the question is updated.

Comment: @PierreCarre How do you even define the integral when the function is not defined at a point. I cannot talk about $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ can't I? . I have to look at Cauchy Principal Value .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Why can't you define the integral for functions not defined at a point? Even if the function is not defined at a set of zero measure, the value of the integral remains unchanged. A different issue is the convergence of improper integrals that may arise. Putting $z=0$ on the contour the question can be answered, and it was surely the purpose of the question. Keep in mind that depending on the contour, the improper integral that arises may be convergent.

Comment: @PierreCarre . Then I suggest you post an answer/comment regarding this , as I have no idea as to how to define the integral at $z=0$ for a general contour .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron when 0 is over $\gamma$, the usual procedure is to construct another contour $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$, that only differs from $\gamma$ by adding a small "bump" of magnitude $\varepsilon$ that puts 0 in the interior of $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$, and study the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=\frac{4 \cos z}{z}$ has a pole of order 1 at $z = 0$. Using the residues theorem, you can compute the integral $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$, whenever $0 \notin \gamma$. For simplicity, if $\gamma$ is a simple curve we have three possibilities:

1. $0$ is in the interior of $\gamma$ and the value of the integral is given by the residues theorem (it does not depend on $\gamma$).
2. $0$ is in the exterior of $\gamma$ and the value of the integral is zero (again, the integral does not depend on $\gamma$).
3. $0$ is on $\gamma$ and you need to study the situation more carefully. This is surely the only way you can obtain $11$ as the value of the integral.

---

Edit: It was not stated in the OP that $\gamma$ needed to be a closed contour... And my answer was based on this assunption. If it can be for instance a line segment, finding a path for which the integral is $11$ is quite trivial, and points 1. and 2. do not apply.

Comment: I see, so $0$ has to be a limit point of $\gamma$ for the integral to be $11$. But how can this be shown by some equation?

Comment: When you define this contour of $\epsilon$ bump. It can have different values as it tends to $0$ for different shapes and the limit will not be unique. Forgive me but I do not understand how it helps to generalize the notion for for the original assumed contour $\gamma$.  I am familiar with the method you are suggesting. For imporper real integrals we often create a small 0 radius circle around the singularity and compute it. How do we guarantee that along all such epsilon bumps the integral would tend to a unique complex number?. I am talking ofcourse for a general function.

Comment: The $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$ contour that I mentioned in a comment does not need to take a part here. I'm just saying that you can find contours that lead to convergent improper integrals and that you can find paths that yield a specific value for the integral.